# Run another exe from compiled python script in new terminal window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a pyinstaller-compiled exe, let's call it scriptB.py from my main (also compiled) scriptA.py, but I'd like to run it in a new (separated) terminal window.
I use this command to run it:

```
subprocess.call('start scriptB.exe', shell=True)
```

It works like a charm, when I run both scripts as .py files. But when I compile them, the 2nd script runs from the main terminal, e.g. it does not separate itself from the scriptA.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: More if a shell issue perhaps than a Python issue. `start` should open a new shell window if the `/b` switch is not used, however in this case it is not being launched from the shell, so perhaps behaves differently.  perhaps launch a cmd.exe process with /c switch? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd